# DownloadAsync error. A method was called at an unexpected time

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, download

In my Windows 8 (c#) app I use this construction for download files.

```
  var tasksDownload = listLinks.Select(link => DownloadAsync(new Uri(link, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), folder, fileName)).ToArray();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasksDownload);

  public static async Task DownloadAsync(Uri fileUri, StorageFolder folder, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName);
            var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            var download = downloader.CreateDownload(fileUri, file);
            await download.StartAsync();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DownloadAsync error.  " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

But, when number of files 1123, I have such exceptions:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in MyApp.exe
>  WinRT information: Quota for maximum number
>   of concurrent operations exceeded.
>  Wait for an operation to complete
>   before starting new ones.
>  DownloadAsync error.  A method was called at
>   an unexpected time.

I want to know:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Release mode solved this problem?
3. If no, how many files I can download at same time?
4. Do you know another solution (not only load part of files, then next part....)

### Update

Now, I split my list with files links to small lists, and trying to download piece by piece, but it doesn't solved problem.
When number of files is small (<20) this exception thrown too.

Comment: You could reuse the `BackgroundDownloader`s.

Comment: I know it, but I have questions about it: Why is this happening?
Release mode solved this problem?
If no, how many files I can download at same time?
Do you know another solution (not only load part of files, then next part....)

Comment: The exception is pretty explicit. There is some quota for the amount of concurrency that one process can use. You can probably benchmark the concurrency and figure it out. The solution would be figure out the limit and adhere to it (queues the files for download).

Comment: Yes, but I need to know accurate quota and what it depends on? I have read the official(or not) source to be sure in my code. Who knows, may be it depends on processor model or other...

Comment: Well it's not documented anywhere, so you might have better luck on the MSDN forums or emailing one of the WinRT product owners.

Answer (score 1):

Personally what I would do is create a List 's and then run each block on each thread. That way none of threads go over the limit. Will also probably increase the speed. If needed I can supply the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a Paralel.ForEach

```
Parallel.ForEach(listLinks, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 }, (link) =>
{
    DownloadAsync(new Uri(link, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), folder, fileName).Wait();
});
```

EDIT: Try and change the 50 with the appropriate number.